# Maven artefact licensing

Tags: maven, licensing

I was asking why Google doesn't upload android artefacts into the maven central repository. Apparently the answer is that user has to accept license before download.

I know that it is possible (and required) to include a license to the artefact. But is it possible to force user to accept it before downloading and usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not possible cause Maven has no such mechanism. Apart from that it's interactive during the download of artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

JFI: It's sad because NuGet in the .NET World has such functionality (

[image]

[Stop License Acceptance popup by Auto Accepting Nuget within visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380187/stop-license-acceptance-popup-by-auto-accepting-nuget-within-visual-studio)